# Explain to a beginner how ArrayList and array are used in this method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

My question relates the one method in an exercise I am doing while learning Java. I understand what the program is supposed to do (one method to determine if a number is prime, and the other to store only prime numbers from an array. I get all that.

I also understand how arrays and arrraylists are different. I also know what methods are. But for some reason my mind can’t wrap around what is happening with these 2 lines when put all together.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> onlyPrimes(int[] numbers) {
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

it’s like merging an arrayList with a method and using an array as a parameter. Can someone break down what is happening here in a *very simple example/explanation?* to a beginner? I cant understand how it’s all working.

Any help by the pros is much appreciated!

```
  public boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if (number==2) {
      return true;
    } else if (number<2) {
      return false;
    }
    for(int i=2;i<number;i++) {
      if(number % i==0) {
        return false;
      } 
    }
      return true;
  }

public ArrayList<Integer> onlyPrimes(int[] numbers) {
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int number : numbers) {
  if (isPrime(number)) {
    primes.add(number);
}
}
return primes;
}


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    PrimeDirective pd = new PrimeDirective();
    int[] numbers = {6, 29, 28, 33, 11, 100, 101, 43, 89};
System.out.println(pd.isPrime(7));
System.out.println(pd.isPrime(28));
System.out.println(pd.isPrime(2));
System.out.println(pd.isPrime(0));

System.out.println(pd.onlyPrimes(numbers));
  }
```

}

Comment: The parameter type is `int[]` and the return type is `ArrayList`. It's not very clear what's unclear.

Comment: Could you please identify which line(s) you would like explained?

Comment: yes, its this line.. that uses array,arrayList both within a method..

public ArrayList<Integer> onlyPrimes(int[] numbers) {

Comment: As I stated, I am a beginner and I understand what the individual parts of the line of code are, but conceptually having an array as a parameter and how arrayList can be data type is confusing I guess. I'm sorry I don't know how to phrase the question better.

Comment: The code is quite ordinary. It's hard to give an answer if you won't spell out the question.

Comment: YourQuestion would be improved if you said more about what specifically confuses you.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ArrayList<Integer> onlyPrimes(int[] numbers) {
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    …
}
```

> my mind can’t wrap around what is happening with these 2 lines

I can understand your confusion. There is a lot going on in those two lines.

### Line # 1

The first line defines the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) of a [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)). The name of the method will be `onlyPrimes`. This method will return a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) to an [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)), an instance of the class `ArrayList` (or return a [`null`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer)). The `ArrayList` object will contain zero, one, or more elements, each element being a reference to an object of the class `Integer`. When a programmer calls this `onlyPrimes` method, she will [pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)) an [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_(data_structure)) (`[]`) of [primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) `int` values (or pass a `null`). Within the body of our `onlyPrimes` method, this passed array will be known as `numbers`.

By this declaration, any calling programmer knows that  if they hand over an array of primitive `int` values, they get back a [collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) objects.

You may be getting especially confused by the fact that Java has two parallel [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) systems: primitives and objects:

- Java was intended to be a thoroughly [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language.
- The primitives type system was also put into Java to (a) make learning easier to the majority of programmers then who were used to [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language))-like languages, and (b) facilitate porting C code into Java.

The two type systems (objects & primitives) are bridged by [auto-boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)#Autoboxing) with [wrapper classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class_in_Java) such as `Integer` for `int`.

### Line # 2

The next line is the first line in the body of our method named `onlyPrimes`. Notice how I corrected your indenting to make clear this relationship between (a) the declaration of a method, and (b) the body of that method. The `{` curly-brace marks the opening of the body of the declared method.

This first line of the method body declares an object reference variable named `primes`. That variable shall hold a reference to an instance of the class `ArrayList`. This instance is a collection of objects of the class `Integer`. The EQUALS sign assigns an object reference to our variable `primes`.

The code after the EQUALS sign instantiates a new collection, an object of the class `ArrayList`. That collection is empty, holding no elements, but is capable of holding references to objects of the class `Integer`. The instantiation returns a reference to the new collection object. That reference is assigned as the content of the object reference variable we declared with name of `primes`.

### Tutorials

I suggest you study a simpler tutorial that goes over the various parts of this code.

- A good place to start is [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), by Oracle Corp, provided free of cost.
- Another excellent tutorial is the book [*Head First Java, 3rd Edition*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-java/9781492091646/)
  by Kathy Sierra, Bert Bates, [Trisha Gee](https://trishagee.com/).

### Improving that code

I would make some changes to that code.

I would mark the method parameter as `final` to ensure that in the method body no other reference is assigned to `numbers`.

The passed argument should be validated, to be sure the calling programmer did not pass a `null`. A handy way to make this check is a call to [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)).

We needn’t repeat the `Integer` as the type of the list in the second line. The compiler in modern Java can deduce that type. So just use `<>`.

Generally it is best to use the highest possible superclass or superinterface that offers the needed functionality. The superinterface of `ArrayList` is [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html). In Java 21 and later, an even higher superinterface is [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) (see [JEP 431](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431)).

I am one of those folks who thinks it generally best to return an [unmodifiable collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable). So after populating the `ArrayList`, I would generate a new unmodifiable `List` by calling [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)).

I would let the text of the code breathe, adding some SPACE characters. The crammed-together style is a historical artifact dating back to the 80-column limits of [punched cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card) and [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal).

```
public SequencedCollection < Integer > onlyPrimes( final int[] numbers ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull( numbers ) ;
    SequencedCollection < Integer > primes = new ArrayList<>();
    …
    return List.copyOf( primes ) ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to break that down. I did the tutorial again and with your help, it makes more sense. I discovered WHY that line gave me trouble. 

First, up until now, I have only seen primitive return types for methods. This is first time seeing a class or array as return. In a similar way, I have only seen primitives or strings as parameters, instead of referencing an array.

I guess those 2 new things threw me a bit. 

Your tips on writing more readable code are right on. I'll use those resources too. I'm at the beginning here, so your patience is appreciated.